# What does this dot and bemol mean?

Tags: notation, classical-music

[image]

I am really cofused. Thank you for your answer by now.

Comment: I removed the second identical copy of the graphics; if something else was supposed to be there, please supply.

Comment: Would you paste more of the song? I googled the single word "Morenica" and the hits I got suggested the song might perhaps be modal, which might go some way to explain the single flat in the key signature. Is the final note of the tune something other than F or D?

Comment: @$Brian Thomas: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=more+nica+mi+me+llama

Answer (score 5):

The dot on the 3rd line is a note head: B♭ (no length defined) and the flat ♭  assigns that there some B will be flattened but we don't know where if we don't see the whole song.

Thanks to the posting of NewGuitarMan  we know now  the B will be flatted  in  the end of the song (2nd last bar) song will B♭.

(B♭ but not the entire song!- that's why the assignment is in brackets)

So this melody isn't in F and neither in Dm. Probably this is a good example of the new term I've learnt recently: Pandiatonicism.

[Pandiatonicism in “She’s leaving home” (Beatles)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95592/pandiatonicism-in-she-s-leaving-home-beatles)

There are several performances of this song but any of them is exactly identical with the one we can see the sheet music here.

Answer (score 3):

The 'bemol' - flat in English - on that middle line denotes all the B notes in the piece will be B♭, (si bemol). Putting it possibly in key F or D minor. Or more likely, I guess, a mode of F.

Why it has brackets, don't know. Possibly as a courtesy reminder. And why there's a note head (dot) as well, still don't know!

Comment: My money's on poorly edited notation software

Comment: Could it be an editorial annotation?  Those are sometimes put in square brackets to indicate that they're not in the original.